# What is the blue triangle on the home button for?

Tags: 11.04, unity

I just noticed a blue triangle icon on my 'Ubuntu' icon. What could it mean?

[image: Blue triangle icon]

Comment: Does the picture you posted have the 'Start' icon? If so, where?

Comment: @mikewhatever I think he's referring to the Ubuntu button in the upper-left, which would be roughly analogous to Windows's "Start" button.

Comment: I am sorry for that. I was really referring to the Ubuntu button in the upper-left. Can't figure out what to call it at that moment.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The little blue triangle is an indicator that shows when an application is requesting user attention (for instance, a dialogue pops up).

The triangle is in the corner, and indicates the direction/place that the user needs to move the cursor in order to reveal the auto-hidden Launcher.

See also:

- [When do things in the new Unity Panel turn blue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38950/when-do-things-in-the-new-unity-panel-turn-blue)

Comment: haha I thought it was a graphic artifact, a bug of some sort... You know like if the screen would be rounded up.