# Blue "gap" behind the Unity launcher button?

Tags: 11.04, unity, launcher, button

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the blue triangle on the home button for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56003/what-is-the-blue-triangle-on-the-home-button-for)

I regularly have a gap in the upper-left corner of the button for the Unity launcher. It is almost like a beveling of the global menu bar. It seems common when using Chrome, but it also occurs when I am using other programs, such as nautilus. I find it quite annoying. Is there anything I can do?

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Ah, thanks to all! Like the other posters with duplicate questions, I thought it was a bug showing my blue wallpaper behind it. Sorry to duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to the blue thing, it is a part of Unity in 11.04, and I don't think you can disable it (at least I don't remember being able to; I'm on 11.10 now). It only appears when an application requires your attention.

Answer (score 1):

When you're saying "gap", do you mean that blue triangular marker in the upper left corner?

It's actually not a gap, it's an indicator that one of the windows in the launcher requires your attention (the same thing is indicated by a blinking/pulsating icon or button in other window managers - since the Unity launcher is hidden most of the time, just pulsating the icon would make ne sense)

I guess it may look like a "gap" if your wallpaper is of a similar blue color... but it is not.