# Will 11.10 still make use of Blue color to alert the user to things?

Tags: unity, 11.10, unity-2d

In Natty, I really enjoyed the "Blue Highlight" feature as detailed in this great askubuntu question: [When do things in the new Unity Panel turn blue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38950/when-do-things-in-the-new-unity-panel-turn-blue)

In Oneiric I notice that the upper left corner is no longer the default launch point for the launcher. Also with the absence of the BFB there is no obvious way of alerting to application notices.

I haven't noticed any "Blue" notices in Oneiric beta. I assumed the Session-Indicator would turn blue when updates are available because there is now an update link in the menu. But no joy. And the volume indicator does not turn blue when its muted and music is playing.

Is this because it's beta? I'm hoping the "blue" feature hasn't been dropped. It was great!

Answer (score 2):

For the most part the "blue" feature is still very much present, it has just moved. Individual launcher icons will have blue arrows when they are requesting attention, and the messaging menu turns blue when it needs to alert you to something. I believe the volume icon does the same thing, but I have no tested this, and I usually don't have my sound muted, so I'm not 100% sure.

There is an indicator for updates that AFAIK will be included in the default install.

Comment: Im really hoping at least the session-indicator will turn blue when updates are available. The little triangles on the launcher turning blue isn't real noticeable.

Comment: @Chad--24216 see my update.

Comment: an update-indicator? why isn't it in beta?

Comment: @Chad--24216 it was only added to the repos a few weeks ago, so it may not have been ready for beta, and I'm not 100% sure if it will be in the final version, but that is highly likely to happen.

Comment: thanks for this info. I think an update-indicator is bad idea--just adds clutter to panel. Highlighting blue both the session-indicator & "software up to date" link in the session-indicator-menu would be preferable. guess we'll have to wait & see :)

Comment: @Chad--24216 the place for that is the Ayatana mailing list.